# Java serialize json property with varying name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize a Map to Java object using Jackson. There are couple different maps that I get and one of them can look like following (in JSON format)

```
{
  "MediaUrl1": "https://someValidUrl2",
  "ApiVersion": "v1",
  "MediaUrl0": "https://someValidUrl1",
  "ToZip": "",
  "FromCity": "xxxx",
  "To": "+1234567890",
  "FromZip": "123456",
  "ToCountry": "xxxx",
  "Body": "Testing more than one media item with message",
  "MediaContentType1": "image/jpeg",
  "MediaContentType0": "image/jpeg",
  "NumMedia": "2",
  "FromState": "xxxx"
}
```

Is there a clean way to handle json properties with keys like

```
  "MediaUrl1": "https://someValidUrl2",
  "MediaUrl0": "https://someValidUrl1",
  "MediaContentType1": "image/jpeg",
  "MediaContentType0": "image/jpeg",
```

Currently I have a POJO that I am generate using

```
objectMapper.convertValue(inputMap, JavaObject.class))
```

There is no way for me to know before hand how many MediaContentType#, MediaUrl# properties I get. Thanks.

Comment: Add List<> mediaUrls = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Why don't you use arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can always map a json to a `Map<String, Object>`.

```
Map<String, Object> obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(src, 
                     new  TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});
```

A Map can easily handle any kind and number of properties.

Comment: While that would work it makes things difficult for downstream consumers. I had thought about just using a JsonNode.

Comment: If there is no good way to handle this and pass as a POJO with (what i was thinking) List of Media entries that have type, url in them then I wouldn't have any other choice but to use something generic like Map or JsonNode.

Comment: If you can decide the structure of the json you can change MediaUrl1, MediaUrl2 and so on to an array named MediaUrls. If you can't change the structure of the json, but you know how many MediaUrls at maximum can be present in a Json you can create a class with MediaUrl1, MediaUrl2, ...., MediaUrl<Max> and leave some of them null

Answer (score 0):

I ended up handling the mediaContentType and mediaUrls separately. Thanks for the answers and comments.